# Get the user in a RouteProviderInterface implementation

Tags: symfony, symfony-cmf, symfony-routing

Is it possible to get the user in a [RouteProviderInterface](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/routing/dynamic_customize.html#bundle-routing-custom-provider) implementation?

My RouteProviderInterface implementation loads a number of new Routes, nothing special. But I want to customize the Routes based on a user setting, if a user is logged in.

If I inject the TokenStorage, the user is not loaded and null:

```
public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage) {

    $this->user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser(); // is null

}
```

Is there another way to get the user?

**Some edit based on comments:**

- I am trying this with a authenticated user. I also dump the user in the actual controller being used and the user does exists there
- All firewalls have "stateless: true" in the config

Comment: Try getting the user from the getRouteCollections method.  Might be available by then.  Just guess though.

Comment: tokenStorage is the right way. Ensure that the token is beeing saved in session. Authentification needs to be stateless. See "configuration" here http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/api_key_authentication.html

Comment: I am agree with @AlexanderKeil , the best way is to injecting the security.tocken_storage service. If the actual user isn't authenticated then it will return null so try to dump an authenticated user in construct method

Comment: Thnx for your responses. I am trying this with an authenticated user, and the "stateless: true" is set on all firewalls.

Comment: i think this is not possible. routing happens before security, because security and the firewalls are configured based on the route and thus come later. see also this old discussion: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3121

Comment: Thnx @dbu, this should be the answer.